# Problem with pagination in Wordpress custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, post, pagination

I created a new template in Wordpress to show the latest articles. After, I will sort them in other ways. My problem is I can not use the pagination correctly.

The next page and previous page are working ok, but the posts are not changed. The first three are the only that are shown.

Can you give me a clue about this ?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Latest Prizes
*/
get_header(); 


// The Query
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

posts_nav_link(' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page');


// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();


get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) on `query_posts()`:

> ...
>
> For example, on the homepage, you would normally see the latest 10 posts. If you want to show only 5 posts (**and don't care about pagination**), you can use query_posts() like so:
>
> `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );`

Change your `query_posts()` to this:

```
query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => get_query_var('page')));
```

Comment: Read the [Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) on this. Unless you're using this function in a page template, this won't work properly at all.

Comment: What exactly did you do? I've been wondering about pagination for my themes too, but I was too lazy to do it ;)

Comment: That made the trick `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("paged=$paged"); ` and I can use it with a pagination plugin now! I have a small question though, how can I change the args of query post so, I order them ASC based on custom fields? The name of the custom field is `ending` and the value is a date in the form of `30-10-2011`

Comment: It seems like you have to run a manual SQL query: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-sort-posts-by-a-custom-field