# WordPress custom pagination for custom posts not working

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm developing custom WordPress theme, in that, i'm using custom queries for fetching data and also using pagination for the bulk data.
I have written code for pagination and it is also showing pagination below posts.
my concern is: whenever I click on 2 page (Pagination), it is showing the same post of page 1 (Pagination).

Please check with below code for your reference:-

```html
<div class="blog_area container">
    <div class="wrapper row">          
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'video',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

        // The Query
        while ($the_query->have_posts()):
            $the_query->the_post();
            $vdoLink = simple_fields_value('vdo_link');
            $showVdo = $vdoLink;
            ?>
            <div class="main_wrapper  col-lg-12 col-md-12 row_wrapper">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class='embed-container'>
                        <iframe src="<?php echo $showVdo;
?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="row ">
                     <h2 class="margin-top-zero">
                            <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
                        </h2>
              </div>
                  <div class='row'>
                        <p><?php the_content('Read More');
?></p>                        
               </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $post->ID;
        endwhile;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                echo paginate_links(array(
                    // 'base' => str_replace( $big, '', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
                ));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have this `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` - perhaps that is evaluating to 1 every time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with pagination in Wordpress custom template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450208/problem-with-pagination-in-wordpress-custom-template)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'showposts' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'video',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    // The Query
    if($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
       <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php 
    wp_reset_query();
    endwhile; else : 
        echo "no posts!"; 
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        echo paginate_links(array(
            // 'base' => str_replace( $big, '', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
        ));
    ?>
```